# Create dynamic field joomla 2.5

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

i trying to build my own module, and i need some help!
So question is: how create dynamic field and make possibility add (N new field) in module admin

Comment: i don't get what you are trying to do. how about posting some code of yours?

Comment: We can't help you without some details of what you're actually trying to do, what you've already done and where the problem is occurring.